# What is the syntax for setting value with ASP?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Quick question:  How do you set defaultvalue with asp?  Here is my code:

```
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ApplicationName" DefaultValue="Membership.ApplicationName"/>
    </SelectParameters>
```

What's the syntax to turn Membership.ApplicationName from a string to actually be parsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in your `Page_Load` method like this:

```
yourSqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(
    new Parameter("ApplicationName", 
                   System.Data.DbType.String, 
                   Membership.ApplicationName));
```

(Assuming you have an `SqlDataSource` on the page named `yourSqlDataSource`)

Comment: But that is in code behind, is there no way to direct inject code into an aspx page like I have in the example?

Comment: @YongkeBillYu I don't know of a way that works with that specific control. Other asp.net controls support the databinding syntax (`DefaultValue='<%# Membership.ApplicationName %>'`) but you can't use that with `SqlDataSource.SelectParameters`